# Visual Studio 2012 Weird Display cshtml

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have one view that isn't displaying properly. The style sheet isn't applying and a couple images aren't either, even though everything is correctly referenced. I'm assuming I'm viewing a cached/corrupted version of the view? How do I go about clearing visual studios cache (note: I do not have administrative privileges)?

For those that want to insist my paths aren't correct, i store my images in Content/images, confirmed all pictures i'm referencing within the view are present, yet some images display and others don't despite the paths being the same and images existing.

I figured out a solution, but am still thoroughly confused. I replaced ../ in the path with ~/ and it worked, which is great, except for the part where all my other views, in the same folder as this view, use ../ and it works perfectly. Why would one view just reject that path drill-down method and it's fine for others?

Answer (score 0):

Ya you will have to reset settings

Close all visual studio
Run command  as devenv / resetsettings

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms241273.aspx